# My mac keeps crashing

Tags: osx

Whenever I try to render an animation on Blender, my Mac OS X computer's blender crashes. I tried doing various adjustments to in the settings, but it didn't work. What can I do to render an animation successfully, without Blender crashing?

Comment: what kind of Mac? what are the specs? Does it crash on the first frame, or a few frames into the animation. What happens if you render as a sequence of .png? does the mac get very hot (feel it) before it crashes? (does it restart?)

Comment: @zeffi This question is on hold as unclear, but I do understand it well enoguh. I will try rephrasing the question

Comment: @TheBro21 Still vague, we need specifics from the asker. Blender crashing and tweaking settings doesn't give us much to go on.

Comment: If blender is crashing it sounds like a bug (something which shouldn't happen at all). These should be reported to the official tracker. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports for